# Using arm64 on GitHub Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I can't seem to get a straight answer to this question.

I want to use GitHub Actions to automate an installation script on macOS running on arm64.

Is this possible today?

Is there an alternative runner with the arm64 architecture that replicates that of the M1/M2 chips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/actions/runner/releases has "OSX arm64 (Apple silicon)".

So, while [GitHub hosted runners](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#supported-runners-and-hardware-resources) might not land on M1/M2 chip yet, you can use self-hosted runners on your own.

Update: [ARM64 runners from GitHub itself are available as public beta, since Oct 2023](https://github.blog/2023-10-02-introducing-the-new-apple-silicon-powered-m1-macos-larger-runner-for-github-actions/)

Comment: Looks like now it's possible to use Apple silicon powered runners: https://github.blog/2023-10-02-introducing-the-new-apple-silicon-powered-m1-macos-larger-runner-for-github-actions/

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an alternative runner with the arm64 architecture that replicates that of the M1/M2 chips?

It should be officially supported now (Q1 2024)

> ### [GitHub Actions: Introducing the new M1 macOS runner available to open source!](https://github.blog/changelog/2024-01-30-github-actions-introducing-the-new-m1-macos-runner-available-to-open-source) (Jan. 2024)
>
> Today, GitHub is excited to announce the launch of a new M1 macOS runner! This runner is available for all plans, free in public repositories, and eligible to consume included free plan minutes in private repositories.
> The new runner executes Actions workflows with a 3 vCPU, 7 GB RAM, and 14 GB of storage VM, which provides the latest Mac hardware Actions has to offer.
> The new runner operates exclusively on macOS 14 and to use it, simply update the `runs-on` key in your YAML workflow file to `macos-14`.